# Too dry in my log home bedroom

Tags: moisture

My log cabin bedroom is very dry. I have tried a humidifier but it seems the wood is absorbing the moisture. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Spread, or paint, the wood with water prohibitive material? Also, seal the leaks should help.

Comment: Is it just in bedroom?  Is something different about bedroom compared to rest of the house, top of house or different walls?

Comment: How do you know it's too dry? Have you measured the humidity? Or are you going by feel? I know some occupants of our house always think it's too dry, while I think it's perfectly fine (and I'm backed up by the humidistat).

Answer (score 1):

The logs cannot be absorbing moisture from dry air so the air must be humid, at least while the humidifier is running.  Maybe it's obvious, but keep the bedroom doors and windows closed while the machine is running.  If the door is open, and you are using a small room humidifier, that would be the problem, not the walls.  If you want the bedroom door open then buy more humidifiers for other rooms or buy a larger unit that will keep the whole house humid.

If you're right about the walls, if they are absorbing some of the humidity you're producing, they will eventually achieve an equilibrium where they are as moist as the air that you want to enjoy.   If your machine can't keep up with your walls' voracious appetite for moisture, get a bigger machine. But that's a little far fetched, hopefully keeping doors and windows closed will do it.